# How to filter result based url parameter in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have WebAPI url (`http://localhost:5134/api/TechDisci/00026`) which returns multiple TechDisciplines for user `00026`. `/TechDisci/` is the controller name and `Get` method returns JSON data.

JSON data has primary and secondary values in the results set. Now User wants to filter this with `primary` and `secondary` by passing in url like this

`http://localhost:5134/api/TechDisci/00026/primary` and `http://localhost:5134/api/TechDisci/00026/secondary`.

My java guys are able to this kind of url thing. How to handle samethig in WebAPI?

Answer (score 1):

You can have "primary" and "secondary" as action (method) names in the controller. Then you will need to add a new route (in class Application.WebApiConfig).

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}"
);
```

Or if "primary" and "secondary" are parameters to the same method. Then you might add this route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{priority}",
    defaults: new { priority = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In this case you will need to add an overload to your Get method that accepts two parameters  (id, priority)

In both cases add the route before the main route, just in case to make sure it is the first one that has a match.